# Proof of the Pythagorean Theorem in a 3 dimension surface.

Tags: triangles, proof-explanation, 3d

Is there any popular, or even not so popular, proof of the Pythagorean Theorem when applied to triangle surfaces in 3 dimensional Euclidean space, that is a triangle in 3d space with vertices at three arbitrary points ($x_1$,$y_1$,$z_1$),  ($x_2$,$y_2$,$z_2$), and  ($x_3$,$y_3$,$z_3$).

Comment: Can one not simply recycle the proofs for its form in 2 dimensions (?)

Comment: depends on what surface they are on a triangle on the surface of sphere has different properties for example.

Comment: um.... what *is* the statment of the Pythagorean theorem applied to three *arbitrary* points.  If the points are arbitrary, they do not form a right angle.

Comment: Are you asking about the pythagorean theorem or the distance formula?

Comment: I will answer this question if you will tell me what the statement (not the proof, just the statement) of the Pythagoren Theorem, for a right triangle $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2),(x_3, y_3)$ in 2 dimensions is.  As the question stands, I honestly do not know what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Three distinct points an the Euclidean space always stay on a plane, so, if they forms a rectangular triangle, we can prove the Pythagorean Theorem with one of the usual proofs on the Euclidean plane.